# How to avoid duplication of type constraint in scala

Tags: scala, types

I encounter quite often the following issue in Scala :

Given a trait

```
trait Foo { def foo: String }
```

and a parameterized class

```
case class Bar[T <: Foo](t: T)
```

I'd like to write a method that work with a `Bar` without duplicating the type constraint, something like :

```
def doSth(bar: Bar[_]) = bar.t.foo
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile and I need to write :

```
def doSth[T <: Foo](bar: Bar[T]) = bar.t.foo
```

Why the compiler can't infer that if I have a `Bar[_]`, the `_` must be a `Foo` ?

Is there a workaround (abstract type will avoid the duplication, but it will add complexity to represent some constraints) ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if

```
def doSth(bar: Bar[_]) = bar.t.foo
```

is essentially the same as

```
def doSth0(bar: Bar[X] forSome { type X }) = bar.t.foo
```

and `type X` is just completely unconstrained. In my opinion, the question should therefore be rather:

*Why does the compiler allow something like `Bar[X] forSome { type X }` at all, even though `X` is not declared as subtype of `Foo`, whereas `Bar` requires the argument to be subtype of `Foo`?*

I don't know an answer to that. Probably it again has something to do with java generics.

---

**Workarounds**

Given the trait and class

```
trait Foo { def foo: String }
case class Bar[T <: Foo](t: T)
```

the following two definitions work without an additional type parameter:

```
def doSth1(bar: Bar[X] forSome { type X <: Foo }) = bar.t.foo
def doSth2(bar: Bar[_ <: Foo]) = bar.t.foo
```

Another option would be to constrain the type of `t` in `Bar` itself:

```
case class Bar2[T <: Foo](t: T with Foo)
def doSth3(bar: Bar2[_]) = bar.t.foo
```